# where is RelatedToAttribute?

Tags: entity-framework, tree, poco

I have a tree structure and need to make a cascade delete. I've read somewhere that marking properties of my poco object with RelatedToAttribute attribute and KeyAttribute would do the trick. But I can't find RelatedToAttribute anywhere.

I am using mvc 3 (.net 4, VS 2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `RelatedToAttribute`. It was attribute in some old CTP version of Entity Framework Feature. `KeyAttribute` is in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly.

Cascade delete in Entity framework requires setting ON DELETE CASCADE in database and in entity model (or code first mapping).